# How to solve the "out of memory error" in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, memory

I want to save 442, three-dimensional images in a cell array. During storage, an out of memory error occurs. To resolve this problem I used the "tall" array but the error not resolved.

Code:

```
for person = 3 : length(Files) 
    ...
    Final_Output{person-2, 1} = tall(Diam_Obj_Remove); 
end
% In each iteration, "Diam_Obj_Remove" is a 3D-image. After 75 iterations the following error occurs.
```

Error:

```
out of memory. type help memory for your options.
```

How to solve the above error?

Comment: Looks like this is too much data to keep in memory. Why don’t you read in the images as you need them and then discard them again?

Comment: @Cris Luengo: Because I need to returns k samples (200 from 442 images) at random.

Comment: Maybe return 200 file names instead? I don’t know what the goal is, sorry if the above sounds silly. In any case, it looks like keeping all your data in memory is not practical, tall arrays are not going to help, you need to come up with a different way of handling images.

Comment: For example, if you are doing machine learning, the 200 samples might be 200 patches of images, not 200 full images.

Comment: @Cris Luengo: The images are binary masks and full (no patches), and I need to some of them at randomly. Ok, I try to find another way.

Comment: How about storing the 442 filenames in an array, a cell array or a structure, and then generating 200 random integers between 1 and 442 that you can use as indices to load the relevant image files (process one at a time and then discard it, so that you don't use too much memory)?